# Best way to handle postgres indexes on delete request?

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

Wondering if an index should be removed from a postgreSQL table, when a row is deleted? I am building an app and deleted many items in the process of testing the app. Now my last table row is index 20 but if I add a new item it starts at index 38. Of course every time I delete a new item this changes, with missing indexes between rows.

I had read that over time, missing indexes and lead to slow deletes. Are there best practices on how to handle this?

Currently I have a very basic model for delete:

```
exports.deleteRequest = (request) => {
  const sql = 'DELETE FROM product_requests WHERE id = $1';
  const value = [request.id]
  return pool.query(sql, value);
}
```

Comment: No, the indexes are maintained by the database server. No need for to do this yourself

Comment: You seem to be conflating concepts. When you refer to indexes 20 and 38, I think you are actually refering to the ID value that is being derived from a sequence. Gaps here are normal over time and don't adversely affect performance. Deletions can leave dead tuples in the data blocks in storage which adversely affect performance by increasing the amount of I/O that must be performed to retrieve query results. PostgreSQL's autovacuum process should minimize the number of dead tuples although there are situations that can interfere with autovacuum. A manual vacuum can be run in those cases.

Comment: Thanks so much, I will look into autovacuum. I was not familiar with that concept or dead tuples. Yes, I was referring with the ID value, my bad. I guess that's just an OCD thing, wanting them to be in sequence, haha.